# Shiny: subsetting a table from a textInput with multiple values

Tags: shiny

I have a simple Shiny app. The user enters a code eg: a1, b1, c1 etc in the textInput.

When only one code is listed it works great, but if the user writes two or more codes separated by a comma it doesn't.

How can the user input as many codes as they like?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel(""),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      textInput(inputId = "textBox",
                label = "Code Search",
                placeholder = "Enter codes here seperated by a comma"),

      actionButton("textSearchButton", "Generate the Table")

    ),

    fluidRow(
      tableOutput("dtOut")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- data.frame(Code = paste0(letters, 1),
                   Description = "Something here",
                   Value = "Some value")

  outputFunc <- function(code, df){

    # # Dummy data
    # code <- c('a1', 'b1', 'c1')

    outTbl <- df[df$Code %in% code,]

    return(list(outTbl))
  }

  textSearch <- eventReactive(input$textSearchButton, {
    outputFunc(input$textBox, df)
  })


  output$dtOut <- renderTable({
    textSearch()[[1]]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your code a bit:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel(""),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      textInput(inputId = "textBox",
                label = "Code Search",
                placeholder = "Enter codes here seperated by a comma"),

      actionButton("textSearchButton", "Generate the Table")

    ),

    fluidRow(
      tableOutput("dtOut")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- eventReactive(input$textSearchButton, {
    # outputFunc(input$textBox, df)
    req(input$textBox)
    codes <- unlist(strsplit(input$textBox, ", "))
    return(data.frame(Code = codes,
                      Description = "Something here",
                      Value = "Some value"))
  })

  output$dtOut <- renderTable({
    df()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Does it respond to your need ?

Comment: Thank you. I thought the output from a textInput was a simple vector, not a list.

Comment: It's not a list, it is a single character-string.